# question based on AM/GM

Tags: algebra-precalculus, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

If $a, b, c$ are positive real numbers and
\begin{align*}
a^{2}(1 + b^{2})+ b^{2}(1 + c^{2}) + c^{2}(1 + a^{2}) = 6abc
\end{align*}

Find $a + b + c$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please let us know what you have tried so that we can better help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the one hand we have $1+a^2>= 2a$, $1+b^2 >= 2b$, and $1+c^2>= 2c$. On the other, from AM/GM we get
$$a^2(1+b^2) + b^2(1+c^2) + c^2(1+a^2) >= 3((abc)^{2}(1+a^2)(1+b^2)(1+c^2))^{\frac{1}{3}}$$ Now, using three inequalities listed at the top:
$$a^2(1+b^2) + b^2(1+c^2) + c^2(1+a^2) >= 3((abc)^{2}(1+a^2)(1+b^2)(1+c^2))^{\frac{1}{3}} >= 3((abc)^{2}2a2b2c)^{\frac{1}{3}} = 6abc$$
With equality only when we have equality in all inequalities above.
So $1+a^2 = 2a$ which means $a=1$ and, similarly $b=1$ and $c=1$.
Hence $a+b+c = 3$